# How to change the image source dynamically in node

Tags: node.js

I want to load the images dynamically but I am getting an error: could not load the image. It is loading all the other content but not the image. Let me know what is going wrong with my code. Please help to correct the code

code link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/keen-dust-7q6lny?file=%2Findex.js%3A42%2C1

**index.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

// Function to replace card
const replaceTemplateCard = function (temp, fruit) {
  let output = temp.replace(/{%NAME%}/g, fruit.name);
  return output;
};

const tempOverview = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/template-overview.html`,
  'utf-8'
);

const tempCard = fs.readFileSync(
  `${__dirname}/templates/template-card.html`,
  'utf-8'
);

const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/data/fruits.json`, 'utf-8');
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

//----- Server -----
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true);

  if (pathname === '/' || pathname === '/overview') {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
    const cardsHtml = dataObj
      .map((fruit) => replaceTemplateCard(tempCard, fruit))
      .join('');
    const output = tempOverview.replace('{%PRODUCT_CARDS%}', cardsHtml);
    res.end(output);
  } else if (pathname === '/product') {
    res.end('PRODUCT');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('<h2>Page not found!</h2>');
  }
});

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  console.log('Listening to request on port 8000');
});
```

**template-card.html**

```
<figure>
  <img src="/images/{%NAME%}.png" alt="{%NAME%}" />
  <figcaption>
    <h2>{%NAME%}</h2>
    <a href="#">Details </a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: You're loading your images from `/images`, but your server does not have any code for that path, so that's a 404. _Which you should respond to with a 404 code_, not with a 200 code. The request was _not_ handled OK and you shot yourself in the foot by not returning the correct error code so that the browser could have told you this immediately. So based on that, you probably want to start using `express` instead of rolling your own server, since that's what everyone else is using too (so it's easy to ask about), and makes route handling _much_ easier to both write, and debug.

Comment: I don't see any code that would load and send an image

Comment: Please see [ask]. Code must be in your question, not just on another site.

Comment: Please add the most relevant code parts to your question, I saw you edited your question, you can undo your changes and add the codesandbox link as an addition

Answer (score 1):

Your server is responding `Page not found` to all the requests other than `/, /overview and /product`.
Add in code for `/image`.

```
    if (pathname.startsWith("/image/")) {
        var img = fs.readFileSync('./' + pathname);

        res.writeHead(200, { 'ContentType': "image/text"});
        res.end(img, 'binary');
    }
```

There is something called `Express`, have a look on that.

Comment: `image/text` seems wrong

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `images` path

```
{
  //...
} else if (pathname.startsWith("/images/")) {
    const img = fs.readFileSync('.' + pathname);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'ContentType': "image/png" });
    return res.end(img, 'utf8');
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/falling-glitter-4jj4mw?file=%2Findex.js%3A42%2C2)